Why were relative pronouns not used? What is the grammatical explanation?

The sun makes the rocks dance in the heat, and the herd children hear one kite (never any more) whistling almost out of sight overhead, and they know that if they died, or a cow died, that kite would sweep down, and the next kite miles away would see him drop and follow, and the next, and the next, and almost before they were dead there would be a score of hungry kites come out of nowhere
The Jungle Book, Tiger Tiger, Part 2

Why were relative clauses not used? What is the grammatical explanation?
I think these sentences should be

the herd children hear one kite (never any more) whistling which is almost out of sight over head
and the next kite which is miles away


"almost out of sight overhead" is a prepositional phrase with locative sense with respect to the whistling.  Compare "They heard the train clattering deep within the tunnel".  That is not the same as "They heard the train, which was deep within the tunnel, clattering".  It says where the clattering sound is located. Of course the train is there too, but it is locating the clattering sound.

When you say I think these sentences should be..., are you seriously inviting us to agree with you that a non-Anglophone learner knows more than Rudyard Kipling about "correct English"? That way lies madness! btw - imho your changes are "syntactically valid", but stylistically weak/ ugly.

@FumbleFingers I don't seriously believe that the OP seriously believes that. I assume rather that they're doing their best to articulate "Based on what I know I would have expected this instead. To Huseyin: we could probably give better answers if you say more about why you expected that.

@AndyBonner: I asked my question in good faith. But the lack of response does rather suggest the OP thinks he (and/or his teachers) are "right", and Kipling is "wrong". Whatever - I closevoted as "pointlessly vexatious" (aka "matter of opinion").

No relative pronoun + preposition
In defining relative clauses, we can also leave out the relative pronoun when it is the complement of a preposition. When we do this, we always put the preposition at the end of the relative clause:
She was at the garden party which I was telling you about. (or She was at the garden party about which I was telling you. or She was at the garden party I was telling you about.) (defining relative clause: which is the complement of about)
